# How to change image contrast and hue with RenderScript

Tags: android, image, renderscript, hue, contrast

I've been using android's RenderScript for about a month and I can't figure out, how I'd change a contrast with it.

I've been able to change Brightness, Blur, and Saturation, but I'm stuck with Contrast and Hue.

I know that it's possible to change contrast with histogram equalization and there's a `ScriptIntrinsicHistogram` class but I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Thank you for your responses.